# In a windy weather on the beach, is it better to play volleyball with a Ball with more Air or less Air?

Tags: mass

I was wondering, in a windy weather on the beach is it better to play volleyball with a fully blown ball or a ball filled with less air?

- What are the important factors that make a ball float easier in the air?
- Please illustrate the effectiveness of the mass of the ball Vs. it's volume in the air with more tangible and exaggerated examples.
- It is obvious that a ball filled with more air is more heavy (has more mass) but we need to know how a heavier ball will float in the air compared to a ball filled with less air in the same condition.
- is density playing any important roll in this between?!